# Why is my exception need to be in try/catch?

Tags: java, android, exception, google-cloud-firestore, try-catch

I'm trying to get information from the database. and check if username is already exists
I'm using the google cloud firestore data base.
I declared the method as throwing an exception that i created.
and when i try to call the throwing of the exception, it tells me that i need to put it in try/catch block.
and I'm wondering why, because I did something similar (but with sqlite with my teacher and it works fine)

my code:

```
@Override
public void isUserExists(final String username, String email) throws UserExistsException {
    Log.e(TAG, "isUserExists: in start of method" );
    // gets the document reference
    CollectionReference usersRef = db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME);
    //Creates and returns a new Query with the additional filter that documents must contain the specified field and the value should be equal to the specified value.
    Query query = usersRef.whereEqualTo(KEY_USERNAME, username);
    //Executes the query and returns the results as a QuerySnapshot.
    // QuerySnapshot = A QuerySnapshot contains the results of a query. It can contain zero or more DocumentSnapshot objects. (is an iterable)
    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            Log.e(TAG, "isUserExists: in the onComplete" );
            //A DocumentSnapshot contains data read from a document in your Cloud Firestore database.
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "isUserExists: in the if statement" );
                for (DocumentSnapshot item : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "isUserExists: in for loop" );
                    //getString() = Returns the value of the field as a String.
                    String user = item.getString(KEY_USERNAME);
                    if (user.equals(username)) {
                      //this throw line will not compile
                        throw new UserExistsException();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I'm implementing this interface:

```
public interface IUser {

void isUserExists(String username, String email) throws UserExistsException;
void isPassesMatch(String password, String rePass) throws PasswordMismatchException;
void checkLength(String username, String password) throws PasswordLengthException, UserNameLengthException;
void checkUserCred(String username, String password) throws UserCredentialException;
void registerUser (String username, String password, String email) throws UserException;
}
```

the something similar i did in class with the teacher:

```
 @Override
public void userExists() throws UserExistsException {
    String sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE userName = '" + this.userName + "'";
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery(sqlStatement, null);
    if(res.moveToFirst()){
        throw new UserExistsException();
    }
}
```

edit (adding the exception that i throw):

```
public class UserExistsException extends UserException {

public UserExistsException(String message) {
    super(message);
}

public UserExistsException() {
    super("User Already Exists");
}
}
```

another edit (adding where the method and its exception is handled
):

```
private void register() {
    String uName = regActEtUname.getText().toString();
    String uPass = regActEtPass.getText().toString();
    String rePass = regActEtRePass.getText().toString();
    String uEmail = regActEtEmail.getText().toString();

    try {
        // checks if the user exissts
        utils.isUserExists(uName,uEmail);
        //checks if the length is fulfilled
        utils.checkLength(uName,uPass);
        //checks if the passwords match
        utils.isPassesMatch(uPass, rePass);
        //registers the user
        utils.registerUser(uName,uPass,uEmail);

    } catch (UserExistsException | PasswordLengthException | UserNameLengthException | PasswordMismatchException e) {
        Log.e("fbdb", "register: " + e.getMessage() );
        TastyToast.makeText(context,e.getMessage(), TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR);
    } catch (UserException e) {
        Log.e("regErr", "register: " + e.getMessage() );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("regErr", "register: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

Comment: in wich line do you have issue?

Comment: question is bit unclear, I will answer of what i understaood and when you invoke a method that throws exception, you either need to catch it and meaningful use of it or throw it further.

Comment: @user2222 i have the issue in the last `if` block, inside the isUserExist method.                @sunil.kms123 i declared the method as throws exception. and when i try to throw it, it says i need to wrap the throwing in try/catch block

Comment: i see that you're throwing it inside onComplete method and not isUserExists method; I think you should handling that exception inside onComplete method with adding try catch bock because overridden methods (onComplete in your case) can throw Exceptions only if method being overridden also throws the same Exceptions.
and this from a java point of view since I have little knowledge of android there may be better workaround.

Comment: and your teacher example was fine because the exception is thrown really inside userExists() method

Comment: any suggestions on how to make the code cleaner and work? I didn't do it in the best practice, i declared a `field` that's called `user` and assigned the answer from the db to it. (`user = item.getString(KEY_USERNAME)`) and checked the `if` outside the onCompleteMethod..

Comment: We don't need to catch RuntimeExpections. In this case UserExistsException extends UserException (probably from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/org/omg/CORBA/UserException.html) and needs to be in try/catch

Comment: i suggest an answer please try it and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
@Override
public void isUserExists(final String username, String email) throws 
 UserExistsException {

     CollectionReference allUsersRef = db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME);
     Query userNameQuery = allUsersRef.whereEqualTo(KEY_USERNAME, username);
     userNameQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
          if (task.isSuccessful()) {
               for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                  if (document.exists()) {
                     String userName = document.getString(username);
                     Log.d(TAG, "username already exists");
                  } else {
                     Log.d(TAG, "username does not exists");
                  }
               }
          } else {
             Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
          }
      }
    });
}
```

Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: I modded it a bit to more fit my code and the way i work, but it does work. Thank You :). i just have one question, is this code efficient? i mean if i have let's say, 500,000 accounts or more, will it take a lot of time to return an answer ? i know you use whereEqualTo, but you also run a loop.

Comment: Could you share thr structure of your firestore in order to look if there is a better way to do the same? I understand that you have a collection, in that collection you have some documents and you want to look in the document if the user exists or not, right? Correct me if I understood it wrong.

Comment: you got it right, i have the main collection -> document -> documents fields, and i want to check the fields. I'm just asking if this code will iterate over all the documents or not.

Comment: Yes, it will iterate over all the documents.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: Okay :) Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a boolean variabale inside isUserExists method, we can update that variable inside onComplete method and rely on it to throw or not UserExistsException.

```
@Override
public void isUserExists(final String username, String email) throws UserExistsException {
    Log.e(TAG, "isUserExists: in start of method" );
    boolean isUserExist = false;
    // gets the document reference
    CollectionReference usersRef = db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME);
    //Creates and returns a new Query with the additional filter that documents must contain the specified field and the value should be equal to the specified value.
    Query query = usersRef.whereEqualTo(KEY_USERNAME, username);
    //Executes the query and returns the results as a QuerySnapshot.
    // QuerySnapshot = A QuerySnapshot contains the results of a query. It can contain zero or more DocumentSnapshot objects. (is an iterable)
    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            Log.e(TAG, "isUserExists: in the onComplete" );
            //A DocumentSnapshot contains data read from a document in your Cloud Firestore database.
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "isUserExists: in the if statement" );
                for (DocumentSnapshot item : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "isUserExists: in for loop" );
                    //getString() = Returns the value of the field as a String.
                    String user = item.getString(KEY_USERNAME);
                    if (user.equals(username)) {
                      isUserExist = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    if (isUserExist) throw new UserExistsException();
}
```

Comment: it still registering user with the same username, it worked, and now it doesn't.